# Changing magnetic flux

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

In the figure, there is a metallic ring inside which there is a dotted region through which constant magnetic field is passing. A wire with sliding contact is moved from position (1) to (2). Will the galvanometer show any deflection?

In this problem, when we take wire from (1) to (2) there is a change in magnetic flux through the loop since initially there was no magnetic field inside and afterwards there is. So, shouldn't there be an induced current in the circuit?
[image: The figure]

Comment: Can you provide the figure?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a wire configuration between 1 and 2, where the sliding contacts are not touching one another. Since you want to evaluate the emf along the conductor, you'd have to choose one closed path encompassing the galvanometer, the wires and one of the two sections of the ring, in order to connect the two sliding contacts. If you choose to include the left part of the ring on the path, while varying from configuration 1 to 2 the area enveloped by the loop never includes the magnetic field. Thus the flux is identically zero during the process, resulting in zero emf. Now let's see what happens if you choose a path which includes the right part of the ring; imagine sliding the contacts back to 1. While doing that, the portion of the ring included in the path increases, until it includes the whole ring in configuration 1. Therefore the surface enveloped by the loop contains the same non-zero magnetic flux during all the process; since the flux is constant, $d\phi/dt=0$ and the emf is 0.

Comment: Nice explanation!